# How do I export the 'theme' used in the Firefox native inspector tools?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Is there a way to export the light/dark theme of the native inspector tools?

Seems like a simple request, and after trawling the `about:config` options I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? It's just a bunch of CSS after all.

Comment: Yep exactly, just the CSS would be ideal. My goal state here is to convert that theme back into a Sublime theme so I have a consistent look between Sublime and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you’re trying to do probably won’t be easy. I’d recommend just using a screenshot and a color picker tool to get the colors. If you really want to go through the trouble of inspecting XUL documents, it’s possible, of course.

You need the [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) extension installed. With dev tools open, launch the DOM Inspector and inspect the `chrome://browser/content/devtools/framework/toolbox.xul` chrome document. The document selection is available in the menu bar.

DOM Inspector isn’t very comfortable, but has roughly the same feature-set as the DOM view in the native dev tools.